# How is it possible to replace a soft hyphen (unicode character or html-entity) in CKEditor4 wysiwyg mode to make the visible for the editor?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I search a way to highlight/replace `&shy;` or `\u00AD` in the wysiwyg mode as e.g. `<span class="rte-visibleshy"></span>`.